# Subgit skipping commits when syncing from git to svn

Tags: git, svn, git-merge, subgit

This may have to do with the order of operations but I'm not sure.  I have an SVN repo which is mirrored to a git repo using subgit.  In git I branched off of master into a feature branch and worked for a while.  When it came time to merge back I first pulled the updates from svn into master, then merged those updates into my feature branch, fixed conflicts, and then merged my feature branch back into master.  Finally, I "git push" and see this output:

```
$ git push
Enumerating objects: 349, done.
Counting objects: 100% (281/281), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (137/137), done.
Writing objects: 100% (193/193), 30.75 KiB | 1.10 MiB/s, done.
Total 193 (delta 90), reused 131 (delta 39)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (90/90), completed with 42 local objects.
remote: Fetching revisions from SVN repository:
remote:   up to date
remote: Sending commits to SVN repository:
remote:   [1/6]  b1b05af => r16591
remote:   [2/6]  a4a5845 => ------ [skipped]
remote:   [3/6]  a88f3bb => ------ [skipped]
remote:   [4/6]  537dbcf => ------ [skipped]
remote:   [5/6]  894e066 => ------ [skipped]
remote:   [6/6]  de2f49f => ------ [skipped]
remote: Sync completed successfully
```

Now I can still see all 6 of those commits in git, but in svn I see only the last merge commit.  Why are commits 2-6 skipped?  How can I see all 6 commits in svn as well?